# "Distribution with sources" feature kills Grails 3 projects in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, grails-3.0

Create new Gradle 3 project, select all default values. You can test project that is runs. Then, stop the project and open `build.gradle` file. You will be prompted with a tip

[image]

(You can configure Gradle wrapper to use distribution with sources. It will provide IDE with Gradle API/DSL documentation)

Select `Ok, apply suggestion`

Now you will be unable to compile or run project anymore with the following error:

```
Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module 'untitled1'
```

Is it possible to restore the project state back to normal?

**UPDATE**

Some block is absent in broken IPR file:

```
  <component name="MavenImportPreferences">
    <option name="generalSettings">
      <MavenGeneralSettings>
        <option name="mavenHome" value="D:/Apps/apache-maven-3.2.3" />
      </MavenGeneralSettings>
    </option>
    <option name="importingSettings">
      <MavenImportingSettings>
        <option name="downloadDocsAutomatically" value="true" />
        <option name="downloadSourcesAutomatically" value="true" />
      </MavenImportingSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
```

[image]

Comment: create a new project and use .ipr format and copy it away.  do above change and compare the changes to the project.ipr.

Comment: See my update please